# What are the benefits of putting grass in my garden, what precautions should be taken

Tags: grass

Reworded (updated) sorry for not being clear, anyway... I have been taking dried up grass clippings from the lawn and have been using it in my garden. I have been putting it around my tomatoes, peppers, cabbage, etc. It helps with keeping the weeds from coming up because there is no sun getting to the weeds underneath. I have been told that the grass clippings can also be very good for the plants because it gives nutrients and stuff of the sort as it decomposes. But being grass I am not certain that it is true, grass being a good fertilizer? Also was told that it makes the soil softer. Like adding sand. That I most certain think is not true but that is why I am asking. (again sorry for not being clear)

Comment: there is no nutritional value for humans from grass as we cannot get much out of cellulose.  did you mean herbivores like cows?

Comment: No, I put grass around my plants to keep other weeds from coming up. I was wondering when they die what nutrients they can provide to the soil

Comment: What makes you think they'll die?  I think you're asking if grass can be used as a green manure.

Comment: Because the grass will be around for example the tomatoes. And the weeds that usually around it will be covered by the grass, so there will be no sunlight hitting them. And without sunlight they usually near do so well and die. I just wonder if it can also be good fertilizer or not.

Comment: They help make soil poorer for the plants that like poor quality soil by taking up nutrients that most plants need.

Comment: I have an answer, but can't post it as one - yes, use grass clippings as a mulch, they contribute nitrogen, give some protection for plant roots from heat and increase soil porosity. But you should only use a thin  layer to prevent the layer going into a soggy mess. This link talks mainly about leaving clippings on lawns, but also covers use as a mulch http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/mulch/mulching-with-grass-clippings.htm

Comment: Could you explain porosity please, thank you fro the answer

Comment: By using thin layers of newly cut grass as a mulch is super for weed control, nutrients not so much as the nitrogen in the clippings will be used for the decomposers to decompose the clippings. Once those clippings are decomposed THEN the micro and macro organisms in the soil can EAT it then take it back down into the soil profile, poop it out, adding decomposed organic matter to your soil without having to manually mix it into your soil.  Guess that is what you mean by 'softening' the soil.  Adding sand, gravel, gypsum to soil for improving is just wrong.  Only decomposed organic matter!!

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use fresh grass clippings as a mulch; they contribute nitrogen, give some protection for plant roots from heat and increase soil porosity.However, they should only be applied as a thin layer - thicker layers turn into a soggy, smelly mess. Link below is largely about leaving clippings on lawns, but does cover use as a mulch

http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/mulch/mulching-with-grass-clippings.htm